# MSSQL.so for PHP 5.3 not loading (CentOS 5.8)

Tags: php, sql-server, makefile, centos5, freetds

I'm trying to install the mssql module for PHP on a server running CentOS 5.8 and PHP 5.3.5. I was able to get it working on the dev server which runs CentOS 5.2 and PHP 5.2.6, and everything seems to match up (FreeTDS installed, module in the modules folder, extension=mssql.so added to php.ini). However, the plugin won't load; doesn't show up in phpinfo() and I get an undefined function error on the test script.

Also of note: phpinfo() lists '--with-mssql=shared,/usr' under the configure command, which is really confusing me.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. Not 100% what the fix was, but I'm pretty sure this was what fixed it.

First off, it probably didn't help I was trying to compile from a copy of php 5.3.16 instead of 5.3.6. Even then, I was running into errors trying to compile it. I found an fix that said to remove this line from `php_mssql.h` in the folder after it's phpized:

```
typedef unsigned char  *LPBYTE;
```

I was then abe to do `make && make install` and it loads with no errors now.